# Why is the limit to observe quantum phenomena $k_B T < \hbar \omega_0$ in cavity QED?

Tags: cavity-qed

In cavity QED you have to cool down the appartus so that quantum effects may be observed in a way that $k_B T << \hbar \omega_0$. I suppose that $\omega_0$ here means the frequency which the cavity doesn't suppress and the frequency equvivalent to the energy difference between the two energy eignstates of the two sate atoms usually used in these experiments. What does this limit describe? What is the physics behind it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $k_b T > \hbar \omega_0$ means the resonant mode is coupled strongly enough to the surrounding degrees of freedom, and those degrees of freedom have enough energy, that the resonator will constantly experience up and downward transitions *induced by the surroundings*. This means the evolution of *just your resonator* is not unitary.

Comment: I don't see how that energy condition speaks to the *strength* of the coupling.  (Other than that, I understand what you are saying.)

Comment: That's not even a universal limit for the existence of quantum phenomena. One can do interference experiments on white light just fine by using spatial rather than temporal coherence (using small angles and small apertures). I am sure there are less trivial examples that also violate the above "condition".

Comment: @CuriousOne I was thinking especially about cavity QED, but I forgot to write it down, so I've edited the title and the text.

Comment: Shouldn't it be kT **"<<"** ℏω? Thanks.

Comment: @kwyip You are right, I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $kT \gt \hbar \omega$, the thermal energy of the system is able to populate noticeably the states of the system you are trying to study. The quantum dynamical effects will be masked by thermal noise as mentioned by DanielSank in the comments. The surrounding degrees of freedom he mentions can be in the system itself, just not the degrees of freedom being studied. It is the beauty of statistical mechanics that as long as the system is not completely isolated, you don't have to worry about what, exactly, is behind the coupling.